# Command works with tilde at the end. How?

Tags: shell, command-line, filenames

I'm on Ubuntu. I have a script called `myscripts` in `/usr/bin/myscripts`

This script simply changes the current directory to

```
~/Work/MyScripts
```

Normally, I simply open a terminal and type

```
~/Desktop$ . myscripts
```

However, today, I accidentally typed

```
~/Desktop$ . StartAllScript~
```

To my surprise, this started Tomcat (~Work/Myscripts/ has a script to start Tomcat). I also tried

```
~/Desktop$ . StartAllScript
```

But that gave me the error

```
bash: StartAllScript: No such file or directory
```

So how did `. StartAllScript~` work?

Comment: It's a backup file.  What does `which StartAllScript~` say?  The dot command searches `$PATH`.

Comment: It's probably hidden. Use `ls -al`. @Mikel

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear `. <filename>` simply tells the shell to run all commands inside the File. The `.` is just a Bourne shell built-in [equivalent](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) of the [bash built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) `source` command (This is also what the shell does to read `.profile` and/or `.bashrc`)

`vim` and other editors like to make backup files (they put them per default into the user directory, sometimes also into the current/working directory (depends on the editor settings) and they most of the time per default call them `<filename>~` so by executing `. StartAllScript~` you told the shell to source the file with the name `StartAllScript~` which is the backup of the somewhen previously edited StartAllScript.

Hope it's clear now.